# TYPO3 Page - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403

Tags: typo3, http-status-code-403

Just overnight I've got a problem with my TYPO3 webpage.

When trying to load the page I've got the message "Access denied" showed, to everyone who wants to load the website. The console log says to me: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403

I have no idea what the matter is. Nothing has changed. It's just there.

TYPO3 website hosted with 1&1 - Germany

The backend is loading and working normally. Except the previews of the page.

Anyone an idea, maybe got the same problem solved?

Comment: What version of TYPO3 do you use? Did you check the log in the TYPO3 backend for further information? There is a log file in your filesystem as well. Please check var/logs or typo3temp/var/logs (depending on your TYPO3 version). And make sure that there is enough free webspace so that TYPO3 can write files to the filesystem.

Comment: I can confirm this problem with TYPO3 9.5.23. I have two pages that produce a 403 error all of a sudden. If I change the urls the pages are shown correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem comes with slugs, try to change the slug, I remember that I had a similar problem and renaming slug solved it.

If it's the case, check if there's no duplicate slug and try to regenerate them.

Comment: When I refresh the slug I get a slug that causes the 403 error. I can solve the problem by changing the slug. But I need '/abc/' and not '/abc1/' or anything else.

Comment: Have you check for duplicate slugs in table tt_content ? May be you have a folder or another page with the same name before being renamed that has generated a same slug that is still present in DB.

Comment: I have found the reason. A File Storage (!) had the same slug.

Comment: Great !  You can add a vote to this answer.